# mySql query give me syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, subquery, syntax-error

give me this error in phpMyAdmin:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table
>               ON brand.seo_name = table.brandName
>   ORDER BY b' at line 8

this is the query:

```
SELECT brand.name, brand.seo_name
FROM brand
JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(product.brand, standard_product.brand) AS brandName
    FROM product
    JOIN standard_product
    ON product.standard_product_id = standard_product.id
    WHERE product.store_id = 1) AS table
ON brand.seo_name = table.brandName

ORDER BY brand.seo_name ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: table is a reserved name, try using `table1` as the alias instead

Comment: it works!!! :D thank you

Comment: ...or tick it `\``; it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` is a reserved word. You should choose a different alias, such as `t`:

```
SELECT brand.name, brand.seo_name
FROM brand
JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(product.brand, standard_product.brand) AS brandName
    FROM product
    JOIN standard_product
    ON product.standard_product_id = standard_product.id
    WHERE product.store_id = 1) t
ON brand.seo_name = t.brandName
ORDER BY brand.seo_name ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: They can use `as table`, just as long as they tick it `\``; it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 'table' for the AS. 'table' is a reserved word. Use something different like 'temptable'.

Comment: That's not entirely true. They can use `as table` just as long as they tick it `\``.